# HTML Form Search Function via PHP MYSQL lookup

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am quite new to HTML/PHP code.

I am trying to build a form that will search a MySQL database based on a key value (Vehicle VRN) being provided. As it stands I have sorted the submit code and I am able to add a new customer to the `Customers` database by clicking 'Submit New'

However, I cannot get the search function to work e.g. enter the vehicle VRN and fill in the rest of the form with that customers information

Here's the HTML form:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>ABC Autorite Ltd</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="style/accordian.pack.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="new Accordian('basic-accordian',5,'header_highlight');">
  <div id="logo"><h1>ABC Autorite</h1></div>
  <div id="basic-accordian" >
    <div id="test-header" class="accordion_headings header_highlight">Customers</div>
    <div id="test-content">
      <div class="accordion_child">
        <h1>Search customer database or submit new details</h1>
            <div class="form_layout">
                <form method="post" id="Customer">
                <select name="title">
                    <option>Mr.</option>
                    <option>Dr.</option>
                    <option>Ms.</option>
                    <option>Mrs.</option>
                </select>

                <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>">
                <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
                <input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone">
                <input type="text" name="email_address" placeholder="Email Address">
                <input type="text" name="address_line_1" placeholder="Address">
                <input type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode">

                <input type="text" name="vrn" placeholder="VRN"> 


                <input type="text" name="make" placeholder="Make">
                <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Model">                
                <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Year">

                <div class="form_buttons">
                <input type="submit" name="search" Value="Search" onclick="form.action='search.php';"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit New" onclick="form.action='submit.php';"/>
                </div>

           </form>  
            </div>    
      </div></div>
    <div id="test1-header" class="accordion_headings">New Job Card</div>
    <div id="test1-content">
      <div class="accordion_child">
        <h1>Create a new Job Card</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="test2-header" class="accordion_headings">Job Cards</div>
    <div id="test2-content">
      <div class="accordion_child">
        <h1>Search for a previous Job Card</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>Copyright ABC Autorite Ltd</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the PHP search script:

```
    <?php
$servername="192.168.0.8";
$username="my_admin";
$password="my_password";
$dbname="ABCAUTORITE";


// Opens a connection to a MySQL server 

$connection=mysql_connect ($servername, $username, $password); 
if (!$connection) { die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

// Set the active MySQL database 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection); 
if (!$db_selected) { 
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

$vrn = $_POST['vrn']; 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE vrn like '%$vrn%'"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
{ 
echo $row['first_name']; 
echo $row['last_name']; 

} 
?>
```

I am just returning `first_name` and `last_name` for now as a 'test' before I add the rest of the values.
This has caused me a few hours of head scratching so I am on here looking for any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate a form by checking to see what `$_POST[]` variable `isset`

```
<?php # customer.php

  if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    echo 'pressed the search button.';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ 
      $form[] = '<input type="text" name="first_name"  value="'.$row['first_name'].'">';
      $form[] = '<input type="text" name="last_name"  value="'.$row['last_name'].'">';
      // etc
    }        
  } elseif(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    # execute code to submit user.
  } else {
    # render the form normally.
    $form[] = '<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="">';
    $form[] = '<input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="">';
    // etc.
  }

?>
```

And just use a standard form.

```
<!-- Still in customer.php -->
<form method="post" id="Customer" action="./customer.php">
  <?php
    foreach($form as $v){
      echo $v;
    }
  ?>
  <div class="form_buttons">
    <input type="submit" name="search" Value="Search" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit New" />
  </div>
</form>
```

### And now your question:

To do with PHP and HTML alone, you would need to do everything in 1 page meaning you would need to generate the form with your desired values. 
Okay.. you don't have to if you don't want to but I would *really* recommend it. This way your code is together and not split apart.

Now there's a million ways to code this, I just picked one that you might be able to easily understand.

### There is an alternative

A combination of Javascript and PHP. Use Javascript  (I would really recommend jQuery) to request a single php file on the server and let it return a json format object. Then use jQuery to update your already rendered form.

### On a side note..

Switch over to PDO for your database to allow for binding your post data to your *prepared statement*. Currently your code is open to SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. So how I see it is this can all be contained within 'customers.php'? rather than having a separate HMTL and PHP file?

Comment: In fact, I can see how this works. I will try and integrate it with my current form design as i would like to keep the current CSS style I have.

Thanks again :)